# How to crop out given points in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

So i'm given to crop out points that are not inside my rectangle or points that lie on the boundrey line. The rectangle is made up of the two points that are taken in by the method p1, p2. so for example if you have the points [(3.0,1.0), (2.0,2.0), (1.5,1.5), (3.0,0.0)] after the crop you should have [(3.0,1.0), (3.0,0.0)] so basically the method should remove all points that are out side the given points..

I solved it this way. But i get some weird errors when it comes to negative numbers..

```
public void crop(Point p1, Point p2) {

    double highX = 0;
    double lowX = 0;
    double highY = 0;
    double lowY = 0;
    if (p1.getX() > p2.getX()) {
        highX = p1.getX();
        lowX = p2.getX();
    } else {
        highX = p2.getX();
        lowX = p1.getX();
    }
    if (p1.getY() > p2.getY()) {
        highY = p1.getY();
        lowY = p2.getY();
    } else {
        highY = p2.getY();
        lowY = p1.getY();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point P = points.get(i);

        if (Math.abs(P.getX() - lowX) < Point.EPSILON
                || Math.abs(P.getX() - highX) < Point.EPSILON
                || Math.abs(P.getY() - lowY) < Point.EPSILON
                || Math.abs(P.getY() - highY) < Point.EPSILON) {
            System.out.println(Math.abs(P.getX() - highX) < Point.EPSILON);
            System.out.println("Keeping: " + points.get(i));
            // keep
        } else {
            System.out.println("Remvoing: " + points.get(i));
            points.remove(i);
        }

        if (P.getX() < lowX || P.getX() > highX || P.getY() < lowY
                || P.getY() > highY) {
            System.out.println("Removing: " + points.get(i));
            points.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

any help solving this problem would be nice i've been stuck for a while now

Comment: consider Math.max()/min() to replace if (p1.getX() > p2.getX()) {
        highX = p1.getX();
        lowX = p2.getX();
    } else {
        highX = p2.getX();
        lowX = p1.getX();
    }
    if (p1.getY() > p2.getY()) {
        highY = p1.getY();
        lowY = p2.getY();
    } else {
        highY = p2.getY();
        lowY = p1.getY();
    }

Comment: What weird errors? Per chance `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the last point is outside of the rect and not close enough to the border? *I wonder where that comes from*;)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." Please be more specific from your question. No one is quite sure what the "weird errors" you are talking about are, not what "this problem" is. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: AlexWien took some time to try to answer your question. It's not that nice to delete it as soon as he does.

Comment: I would suggest that if you found a solution you put it in the answer section instead of in your question, as you were told earlier. If you won't do so I'd be happy to make a community wiki answer out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came up with this as a solution to the problem

```
public void crop(Point p1, Point p2) {
double highX = 0;
double lowX = 0;
double highY = 0;
double lowY = 0;
ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
if (p1.getX() > p2.getX()) {
    highX = p1.getX();
    lowX = p2.getX();
} else {
    highX = p2.getX();
    lowX = p1.getX();
}
if (p1.getY() > p2.getY()) {
    highY = p1.getY();
    lowY = p2.getY();
} else {
    highY = p2.getY();
    lowY = p1.getY();
}
if (p1.equals(p2)) {
    list.add(p1);
    points = list;
    return;

}
double i = 0;
while (i < points.size()) {
    Point P = points.get((int) i);
    if (P.getX() < highX + EPSILON && P.getX() > lowX - EPSILON
            && P.getY() < highY + EPSILON && P.getY() > lowY - EPSILON) {
        list.add(P);
    }
    i++;
}//thank god
points = list;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is the `java.awt.Rectangle` for integer  and `java.awt.Rectangle2D` class with the method `contains(x, y)`.

This will solve the case when the points is inside the Rectangle or on the left or upper border.

For good reasons you should not treat points on the right and lower border as beeing inside.
Talk with the person that demandend that.

Otherwise you may get points that are inside both of two touching rectangles, and this is not a good solution.

Further ist is usual to specify: "If a point is exactly at the border, the method may return true or false".

However for axe-parallel rectangles the "to-be-inside-or-on-the-border" task is easy to solve. Look at the src of that java methods and change < to <=. (or similar)